# increase/decrease the distance between clusters in histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

It seems that increasing the gap value in a histogram chart, will decrease the bar width. Why? That means, each cluster has a fixed width

I want to increase the distance between xtics (not the distance between each two bars) in a histogram. How can I do that?

```
set style histogram cluster gap 0.1
```

[image]

```
set style histogram cluster gap 3
```

[image]

Comment: Chart has fixed width, and gnuplot arranges all bars and gaps in the width of chart.  Total number of bars and gaps are increased, width of each bars and gaps will be decreased.   Use "set style histogram cluster", this will put 2 gaps between xtics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the spacing between the xtics you must increase the canvas width when setting your terminal:

```
set terminal wxt size 1000,500
```